# Why have additional symbols on a Turing machine?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

What is the point of non-binary printed letters on a turing machine? I understand that these need to be omitted to get a computable number, but why are they used in the first place?

Comment: You mean, why a TM could have an alphabet other than $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: Because TMs are a formalism to think about computation, and sometimes having more symbols than $0$ and $1$ makes thinking about problems easier. They are not a blueprint for hardware.

Comment: @G.Bach Together with an example, this would make a fine answer, I think.

Comment: @Raphael I figured that, but couldn't come up with an example. It's been a while since I thought about this stuff in detail.

Comment: @G.Bach I thought of nothing more than separating, say, numbers of a list. If you can use only binary symbols, you immediately need two bits per bit in order encode separators uniquely, rendering everything far more complex. Anybody who has done any proof on TMs has seen "mark that symbol" or something like that, which causes similar problems. (I just did not want to steal "your" answer.)

Comment: Why even give a TM as an example? It seems sufficient to point out that the "point" of having more than two letters in the English alphabet is more or less the same as the "point" of allowing more than two letters in a TM's tape alphabet. The answer could range from "it's convenient" to "that's just how it ended up", with everything in between being equally as valid. Really, the question should be why computer hardware relies on binary representations, not vice versa. Another interesting question might discuss unary alphabets. The answer to this question, as asked, is "because!"

Comment: By the way, for most interpretations of `I understand that these need to be omitted to get a computable number` I can imagine, your understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turing Machines are an abstract model of computation, their purpose is to define in a mathematical way what problems are theoretically computable and which are not.

It is true that a binary alphabet is enough to reach the full expressive power of Turing Machines. However, when playing with them "in practice" to prove theorems and to communicate these proofs, it can be more convenient to use more symbols, instead of encoding everything in binary. We could always go back to binary if it's absolutely needed.

An extreme example of the same sort would be "why are we still using 26 characters to write texts, now that we know that two are enough? It would save time when learning the alphabet!".

Comment: You are also much better off with a blank symbol. Otherwise everything has to be coded in unary.

Answer (score 1):

Turing machines with many symbols can be simulated by Turing machine with two symbols. The idea is to consider groups of bits as representing one symbol, in the same way that files are stored in the computer byte by byte. In that sense, having more symbols gives you no more power than a single symbol. Moreover, the simulation has "constant throughput" — it only slows down the machine by some constant.

There is a fine point regarding input encodings. Usually inputs are blank-separated or blank-terminated. If you have only two symbols and are using this convention, then everything has to be encoded in unary — $1^n0$ for the number $n$. This has a strong effect on input *length* and so on running times (making them appear much *faster*), so either you use an unconventional encoding (say encode "characters" in groups of two symbols), or you need to have at least three symbols (including the blank symbol).